# How do I export my Dataflow worker logs to Cloud Pubsub?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

I'd like to run some secondary processing on my worker logs from Cloud Dataflow.  Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by configuring [logs export](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export) from Cloud Logging.

First, navigate to the *Exports* table in the Cloud Logging UI:

[image: Select "Exports"]

On the Exports page, follow these steps:

1. Select the *Dataflow* service.
2. Deselect **All sources**.
3. Click **Add item** and select *dataflow.googleapis.com/worker*.
4. Select a Pubsub topic to publish to.

[image: Export page]